# passing struct to a function c++ (efficiency)

Tags: c++, performance, function, data-structures, struct

I'm testing timings on a simple code and I don't see the difference.
In first block it acts like only the pointer is passed, in case 2 and 3 it acts like copying it by value not by reference, the whole struct.
edit:::
struct:

```
struct e{
    vector<int> a;
};
```

This code takes 0 sec:

```
void ola(e &a)
{
    a.a[0] = 1;
    a.a[9999] = 1;
}

int main()
{
    e *a;
    a->a.resize(10000000, 0);
    a->a[0] = 2;
    a->a[99999] = 2;
    ola(*a);
    cout << a->a[0] << " . " << a->a[99999] << endl;
    letras.resize('z' - 'a' + 1);
    string entrada;
}
```

This one takes 0.15 sec:

```
void ola(e &a)
{
    a.a[0] = 1;
    a.a[9999] = 1;
}

int main()
{
    e a;
    a.a.resize(10000000, 0);
    a.a[0] = 2;
    a.a[99999] = 2;
    ola(a);
    cout << a.a[0] << " . " << a.a[99999] << endl;
    letras.resize('z' - 'a' + 1);
    string entrada;
}
```

But there shouldn't be any difference. Maybe it's because in assembler it has to copy all values of struct when passing it, so I tried this one:

```
void ola(e *a)
{
    a->a[0] = 1;
    a->a[9999] = 1;
}

int main()
{
    e a;
    e* b;
    a.a.resize(10000000, 0);
    b = &a;
    a.a[0] = 2;
    a.a[99999] = 2;
    ola(b);
    cout << a.a[0] << " . " << a.a[99999] << endl;
    letras.resize('z' - 'a' + 1);
    string entrada;
}
```

On last one I passed only a pointer to a, and it takes 0,15sec too. Why do I see this difference?

Comment: 1. In the first code block, `a` is uninitialized but you dereference it.  2. If you are measuring something as 0 seconds, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: 0 seconds means it is that fast that it says 0, it's maybe 0.005 s, by the way, added struct info @MooseBoys

Comment: General advice in such type of problems is that you should compare the assembler generated by your compiler. For gcc you can use -S compilation flag for this.

Comment: The times you measure are too close to be meaningful. Such short runs can be significantly affected by other activity on your machine, cache misses etc. Make the times at least an order of magnitude larger. Also, if what you're asking is basically if passing a reference or a pointer should be the same, than they should.

Comment: @eran It should be the same, I was just testing that because I studied in computer arquitecture that vectors are "automatically" parsed by reference but structs aren't so I tried to see the difference on the efficency

Comment: You're mixing concepts. The architecture has no idea if you're passing stuff by reference or using a pointer - it just runs the instructions created by the compiler. The are some performance issues when using both arrays and structures (can make them prefetch-friendly). Anyway, I'm all for trying stuff you learned, but those kind of experiments are rarely as clean as you'd want them to be. Therefore, they must be long enough to minimize side effects.

Comment: Daniel when you are writing parse (to read and interpret) you mean to write pass (to give to).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right idea. Profile your code and test your assumptions, but make sure the code actually matches your expectations and the profiling is accurate.

First point: vectors are not always passed by reference. The compiler will do everything in its power to pass by reference, elide, or pull any one of a number of similar tricks because it is less work, but when it cannot, the vector will be copied.

Second point:
Timing code is tricky. Too tricky to cover here. But naive assumptions are nearly always wrong. One run is not sufficient. Many runs and statistical analysis of those many runs is often required.

I'm going to ignore the fact that case 1 doesn't work due to an uninitialized pointer taking it on a trip into undefined territory. That's just a side-show.

Case 1:

```
void ola(e &a)
```

`a` is passed by reference, practically and literally here. No data will be copied other than an address.

```
ola(*a);
```

`a` is dereferenced to satisfy requirement for a reference, so we are using the value at `a`. The fact that `a` is a pointer is now irrelevant. `ola` gets a reference.

Case 2:

```
void ola(e &a)
```

Identical prototype. Also passed by reference. No data will be copied other than an address.

```
ola(a);
```

`a` is passed by reference.

Case 3:

```
void ola(e *a)
```

Passed by reference again, but this time the reference is a pointer. No data will be copied other than an address.

```
ola(b);
```

`b` is a pointer to `a` and `ola` takes a pointer. No work required. `a` is passed by reference.

To pass by value, OP would have to write:

```
void ola(e a)
```

This *may* do a copy if the compiler feels like it. A smart enough compiler would note that there are absolutely no side effects of `ola`, a copy is modified and discarded, and compile the function call out. A naive profile of this could show amazingly efficient performance because nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

In the first block you're using a pointer (**a**) that is not initialized before being used.
I suspect you forgot some part of the code in your post.

Moreover, it's not clear what you want to do exactly and what are you trying to time ?

Answer (score 0):

First program probably crashes before doing anything useful. a points to an invalid location in memory. It should be:

```
e *a = new e();
a->a.resize(10000000, 0);
```

Comment: it didn't crash and it gave me a correct answer but you might be right, then, why does it take the same time to parse the struct as a pointer than parse it foo(struct a) ? in second case it should take longer as it has to copy all elements

Comment: There is no copying involved. In all cases value is either passed by ref or ptr. Only time it takes is to allocate the vector.

Comment: I made a test parsing it without pointer, parsing it by value and it took the same time :/

Comment: If you want to pass the object by value you should use `void ola(e a)` as function signature. In this case, value of `a` cannot be changed and compiler is free to optimize it away.